# asp:Menu and css selected item

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, sitemap

I am having problems configuring my asp:Menu. When I use any css, the menu items don't get selected anymore. I've tried 3 versions, and each has it's drawback.

This one work the best for css, but the selected item doesn't get selected.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"DataSourceID="smdsMaster" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle ForeColor="White"/>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle ForeColor="White" />
    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu 1" NavigateUrl="~/Menu1.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu 2"  NavigateUrl="~/Menu2.aspx" >
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Submenu 2" NavigateUrl="~/Submenu2.aspx" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu 3" NavigateUrl="~/Menu3.aspx" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

This one shows selected, but I can't use images as backgound for the menuitems. If I add css in it, the selection won't show anymore. And the sub-item is always present.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="smdsMaster" DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
 Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticSubMenuIndent="0px"  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" OnMenuItemDataBound="Menu1_MenuItemDataBound"
 ForeColor="White" BackColor="#EE7B00" StaticItemFormatString="<p align=center> {0}" DynamicItemFormatString="<p align=center> {0}">
    <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="#EE7B00" Width="110px" Height="31px" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#CCCC00" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#CCCC00" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" Width="110px" Height="31px" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#CCCC00" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#EE7B00" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#CCCC00" />
</asp:Menu>
```

How can I have both: images as background for my menuitems, with text over it, AND show witch item is selected.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is the CSS that goes with it:

```
.page .header_menu .menu
{
    !margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

.page .header_menu .menu li
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 31px;
    list-style: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
}

.page .header_menu .menu li a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 31px;
    width: 110px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../Assets/btn-back-normal.gif);
    color: white;
    margin-top: -1px; /*Chrome = -16, IE = 0*/
    z-index: 1;
}

.page .header_menu .menu li a:hover
{
    background-image: url(../Assets/btn-back-over.gif);
    color: white;
    margin-top: -1px; /*Chrome = -16, IE = 0*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 110px;
}

.page .header_menu .menu li a:active, .page .header_menu .menu li a:selected
{
    background-image: url(../Assets/btn-back-selected.gif);
    color: white;
    margin-top: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 110px;
}

.page .header_menu .menu:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 110px;
}
```

I also tried to set these, but only the first item stays selected, no matter wicht one actually is selected

```
<style type="text/css">
#NavigationMenu a{padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; height: 26px; background-color: #EE7B00;}
#NavigationMenu a.static{ padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; height: 26px; background-color: #EE7B00;}
#NavigationMenu a.static.selected{padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; height: 26px; background-color: #cccc00;}
#NavigationMenu a.dynamic{padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; height: 26px; background-color: #EE7B00;}
#NavigationMenu a.dynamic.selected{padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; height: 26px; background-color: #cccc00;}
</style>
```

Comment: Try showing us your HTML + CSS, not your .NET source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your .aspx page and examine the source you will notice that the menu item `<a>` (hyperlink) tag has a selected class called *a.selected.static* you can implement your own version of this in your code and override it by applying `!important` to the CSS class.

The sample below displays a simple menu with image menu items and highlights the image with a red border when selected:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.selected.static
        {
            border:2px solid red !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/1.jpg" Text="Item 1" />
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/2.jpg" Text="Item 2" />
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/3.jpg" Text="Item 3" />
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I now have the first item selected. Problem is, it's the only one that gets selected, no matter witch one I click. What Am I still missing?

Comment: I Found my bug: If a child node was selected, I was selecting the parent node instead. Since my first item is the parent of all, it was the only one ever showing selected. I'll do somthing more specifie for the child nodes.

Comment: My guess is that all the other css styles and menu properties you have set are overriding the selected style.I would suggest using the exact code in my sample and removing any other css properties which may interfere with the menu.I've tested my sample in IE,Firefox & Chrome and it successfully selects between menu items and sets the border

Comment: Simple is always best. I flushed all my over-complicated styling and formating, and used your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Denis BINGO! Nice Work